# how to send value of query string in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am making a `Crystal-Report` from data of `GridView`. The `GridView` has three columns in which two columns are filled with values coming from DataBase in a label and third column has a CheckBox which on check sends the value of these two columns as query string to the .cs page of `Crystal-Report`. The column value is used by the stored-procedure and then result is shown in the `Crystal-Report`.
Now my problem is if user checks two `CheckBox` then the value of both columns should be sent to `Crystal-Report` page as array. How to implement this

My code behind in `GridView` page is

```
  protected void ChkCity_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gdCityDetail.Rows)
        {
 bool ischecked = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox2")).Checked;
            if (ischecked == true) 
{
int getrow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  Label label1 = (Label )gdVilDetail.Rows[getrow].FindControl("label1");
                Label label2= (Label )gdVilDetail.Rows[getrow].FindControl("label2");

                Response.Redirect("~/crystal report/Landowner.aspx?Yojna=" + label1.text + "&Village=" + label2.text);

            }
```

and the code on .cs page of `Crystal-Report` is

```
 private void cityreport()
    {
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Showvillage", Constr1);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yojna_No", Request.QueryString[0]);
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Village_Code", Request.QueryString[1]);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot pass Array or any other Objects through Query string except string values. Rather you can use Session Variable.

Try this..

In page One.

```
//Set
Session["Variable"] = ArrayObj;
```

In page Two.

```
//If String[]

string[] arry = (string[])Session["Variable"];
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Check this link. There is a code in the link which has used array to send the value with querystring. I hvn't tried that but may be that will work too.

> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/298718/array-in-query-string